# ADFS and relying party web form

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, adfs

We are in the process of configuring our ADFS server to allow SMAL authentication from a third party web application.

We are slightly confused as listed below:

1. We received metadata file and configuration steps from relying party. We will configure as suggested by the relying part. My question is do we need to provide them in return so SSO works? For example, a certificate or any configuration information from our ADFS servers?
2. We need to set ForceAuthn flag in our ADFS server. Where do we need to set this flag?

Any pointer to these questions is very much appreciated.

Please not that authentication is from web URL to ADFS server.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2):

1. Your AD FS metadata URL should be provided to the relying party. Chances are they might allow you to do the relevant configuration yourself on some web portal. Your metadata URL is like below. replace sts.contoso.com with your service name as appropriate https://sts.contoso.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml . This URL is accessed anonymously without any authentication and ideally should be internet accessible. Else, you should access it internally using a web browser and save it as an XML and provide to the relying party.
2. ForceAuthn is how you force a new authentication each time at the IDP ( AD FS) . If doing SP initiated logon, then they (relying party) should send it in the samlp:authnrequest they generate. Another option is to configure -AlwaysRequireAuthentication to $true using set-adfsrelyingpartytrust cmdlet. This only works for Windows Server 2012 R2 based AD FS.

Answer (score -1):

They will also likely need the public key of your token signing certificate.
Instructions for exporting that can be found here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737522(v=ws.10).aspx